# How can I install a global custom provider for puppet?

Tags: windows, linux, configuration, puppet, chocolatey

I'm wanting to use the [chocolatey puppet provider](https://github.com/rismoney/puppet-chocolatey) as a package source for windows. My understanding is that I have to save the file to `{module}/lib/puppet/provider/package/chocolatey.rb`. That seems ok if I'm only ever going to use it in one specific module. But what if I want to make it available to all my modules?

Comment: Apparently I was totally missing the boat on this one. Just install it as a module under the `chocolatey/lib/puppet/provider/package/chocolatey.rb` folder and it's available to all the modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, for answer sake -  Just install it as a module under the chocolatey/lib/puppet/provider/package/chocolatey.rb folder and it's available to all the modules.

Answer (score 0):

I added this since it couldn't find the environment variable. This will only happen when you install Chocolatey as part as your puppet manifests.

```
if chocopath.empty?
    puts "Could not find environment variable value for ENV['ChocolateyInstall']. Using C:\ChocolateyInstall instead"
    chocopath = 'C:\Chocolatey'
  end
```